# No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'

Tags: android, xml, styles, android-manifest

Sorry for my english. I try change action bar collor. And i have this error:

> error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name '@android:style/ 
>   Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.

I have minSdkVersion = 12

style.xml

```
    <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
         <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

      </style>

//this is error
      <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
         <item name="android:background">#FF9D21</item> 
      </style> 
     </resources>
```

**UPD**

I have added appcompat_v7, but its not work

[image]

**UPD**

now style.xml looking that:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
             <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

          </style>


          <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
             <item name="android:background">#FF9D21</item> 
          </style>
```

in manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
```

i have error:

> 03-05 12:45:33.860: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.test6/com.example.test6.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with this activity.

if i change manifest like that:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
```

no error but after this no change color action bar

Comment: add `appcompat_v7` in your project.

Comment: @MD thanks for answer, i had add  appcompat_v7 but isnt work(

Comment: If you added appcompat_v7 as dependency then why should you add .jst in libs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse` instead .

On a side note, [the `styles.xml` file on appcompat_v7](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/4c47ef63519d579b9ac029fcb6dcc81e38d82984/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/styles.xml) suggests that `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse`is deprecated.  `@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse` is an alternative.

Comment: Is your Activity extending ActionBarActivity? Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem in my **v21\styles.xml** file.

Solution:

`parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse"`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
<style name="AppBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
```