# error: invalid parent reference 'style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'

Tags: android, android-appcompat

`theme.xml`:

```
<style name="Theme.App.ActionBar" parent="style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <!--<item name="elevation">0dp</item>-->
</style>

Error:(160, 5) error: invalid parent reference 'style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.
```

**APP model**: `buding.gradle` like this:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

}

I add com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0, but whay it is still like this.

I am new to android, what's the point of this.

thank you for your help.

Comment: Please read this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877156/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-androidstyle-widget-appcompat-l?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 14):

For Android 2.1 and higher

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
```

For Android 3.0 and higher only

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
```

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced same issue, I tried the following: `@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse`

the app worked but having a transparent (white) app bar.

So I used this:
`@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse`

it worked perfectly; as designed.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same Problem. This worked for me:

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
```